# Javascript Nested functions with toString

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please explain this code? This example is taken from javascript.info.

I don't understand, especially the `f.toString = function(){ return sum}` part.

```
function sum(a) {

   var sum = a 

   function f(b) {
       sum += b
       return f
   }

   f.toString = function() { return sum }

   return f
}

alert( sum(1)(2) )  // 3

alert( sum(5)(-1)(2) )  // 6

alert( sum(6)(-1)(-2)(-3) )  // 0

alert( sum(0)(1)(2)(3)(4)(5) )  // 15
```

Comment: That code is convoluted. It could've been written more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the author of that snippet wanted to achieve one goal, that is, something like "faking" *operator overloading* which is possible in other languages.

Since `sum` returns a *function reference*, we could not go like

```
sum(5) + 5;
```

That would result in something weird like `"function sum() { ... }5"`. That is because ECMAscript calls the `.toString()` method on objects when invoked in a *Math* operation. But since he overwrites the `.toString()` method returning `sum` (which is a number), it does work again.

Answer (score 0):

All objects in javascript 'inherit' a field called `toString` that exists on the prototype of boject. After assignment `toString` exists as any other field on f. It is assigned a as a function, and can be invoked as such:

Comment: "The Function object overrides the toString method inherited from Object; it does not inherit Object.prototype.toString. " .. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString

Comment: @kabaros - great. And your point is just what? You seem to be trying to refute something that was never claimed nor insinuated.

Comment: my point is that in case of Function, it doesn't inherit from PROTOTYPE.toString as rich mentioned (and as MDN documentation confirm) .. if it was actually inheriting from prototype then the code in the original question wouldn't work. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `sum` is a function that can be chained into multiple calls. `toString` is a method of the object that returns what should be shown if the object is used in a context that expects a string.

Personally, I think it'd be easier like this:

```
function sum() {
    var l = arguments.length, i, a = 0;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) a += arguments[i];
    return a;
}
alert(sum(1,2));
alert(sum(5,-1,2));
alert(sum(6,-1,-2,-3));
alert(sum(0,1,2,3,4,5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet from [MDN article about Function.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString)

> The Function object overrides the toString method inherited from
>   Object; it does not inherit Object.prototype.toString. For Function
>   objects, the toString method returns a string representation of the
>   object in the form of a function declaration. That is, toString
>   decompiles the function, and the string returned includes the function
>   keyword, the argument list, curly braces, and the source of the
>   function body.
>
> JavaScript calls the toString method automatically when a Function is to be represented as a text value, e.g. when a function is
>   concatenated with a string.

So basically, what this "annoying" piece of code is doing is providing an implementation for Function.toString that will be used when when a string representation is required, i.e. when **alert** is called ([alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.alert) takes a string as an argument).

For the rest of the code, it's just calling itself recursively to compute the sum of the arguments.

Comment: .. and it's annoying because it requires a post on SO and researching MDN to understand it .. it's a nice mental exercise but personally, I wouldn't write code like this in any real-life project